# C++ Logic Error (boolean)

Tags: c++, boolean-logic

```
template <class T>
bool BST<T>::printSubtree(T item)
{
  int id;
  bool result;
  if (root==NULL)
  {
    cout << "Empty Tree, Please insert data" << endl;
    return false;
  }

cout << "Enter ID to print sub-tree" << endl;
cin >> id;
result=searchSubTree(id, item);

 if(result == false)
 {
     cout << "Record Not Found" << endl << endl;
 }
//preOrderPrint();
return true; 

}

template <class T>
bool BST<T>::searchSubTree(int target, T &item)
{

BTNode<T> *cur, *curtemp;
bool flag = false;
if (root==NULL)
{
    cout << "Empty Tree, Please insert data" << endl;
    return false;
}
cur = root;
curtemp = root;

while(!flag && cur!= NULL)
{
    if(curtemp->item.id == target)
    {
        flag = true;
        root = curtemp; //promote desired node to become root temporarily
        inOrderPrint();
        flag = true;
    }

    else if (curtemp->item.id < target) //target value greater than current value, search right sub-tree
    {
        curtemp = curtemp->right;
    }

    else if (curtemp->item.id > target) //search left sub-tree
    {
        curtemp = curtemp -> left;
    }   
    root = cur; //set the root position to its ori place
}

return flag; 

}
```

In the code above, everything is running fine. However, why I tried to input a value which doesn't exist(id input) , my program just crash, it can't proceed to `if(result == false)`. May I know what's the problem over here?

Thanks for your guides!

Comment: What did you observe inspecting your code line by line with the debugger?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your while statement shall use curtemp instead of cur.

```
while(!flag && curtemp!= NULL)
```

Comment: I appreciate your help which got my problem solved, thank you!